# OrderByDescending for JArray inside a JArray

Tags: c#

I have a JArray in JArray as below, how to OrderByDescending plate & score?
I try

```
_ja_lpr = new JArray(_ja_lpr.OrderByDescending(obj => (double)obj["plate"] 
["score"]).ThenByDescending(obj => (double)obj["vehicle"]["score"]));
```

it does not work, because each plate and score inside a JArray.

any help would be appreaciated
many thanks in advance

```
[
 {
    "ja_info": [
      {
         "plate": {
             "number": "B1",
             "score": 0.903
         },
         "vehicle": {
            "type": "Car",
            "score": 0.62
        }
      }
   ]
},
{
   "ja_info": [{
    "plate": {
      "number": "B2",
      "score": 0.913
    },
    "vehicle": {
      "type": "Car",
      "score": 0.72
    }
  }]
},
{
   "ja_info": [{
    "plate": {
      "number": "B3",
      "score": 0.900
    },
    "vehicle": {
      "type": "Car",
      "score": 0.63
    }
  }]
```

}
]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to parse the JSON to your own custom class?

Comment: 99.9% of JSON issues are better solved by serialising to concrete types instead of messing about with `JArray` etc. https://app.quicktype.io?share=j8aqZlji5ucO4YdyXupz